# Which is faster: loading images via repo, or loading via ACF/Media Library in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, performance, advanced-custom-fields

I have two methods of loading images in my mind right now during WP Theme Development:

1 - I store an image in a folder within my repo, and load it as a background image, defining it statically in CSS/Inline CSS.

2 - I store an image in the WordPress Media Library, upload it to an Image Content field within Advanced Custom Fields, and then load the src using inline styles in the template.

Which of these is faster?

My mind is telling me #1 because I don't have to go and get the img url from the uploads folder as directed by ACF, which is stored in the database but equally I don't know WordPress that well, so I might be wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two observations:

1. You write that this question comes up "during WP Theme Development", and
2. You're loading it "as a background image".

If the end-user of the theme won't be uploading their own image for that part of the theme, then #1, the "store in repo" method, is definitely the way to go. Simpler, too.

However, if this background image is expected to change from time to time, you might be smart to leverage Advanced Custom Fields and save yourself the boilerplate code of adding image-upload fields to WP.

This being the case, you can still encourage your theme's end-users to use some cache (to cut down on those db queries to reference the image) and/or image CDN (to improve the HTTP part of the image's journey) [plugins in the WordPress plugin codex](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/cache%2C+image+cdn/).